# Boolean operation in extend script for illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

Is there a way to do vector boolean operations – the equivalent to pathfinder when using the GUI – in Adobe Extend Script?

To subtract one shape from another, or to get the intersection of a two shapes, or combine the two.

A visual example of this would be:
[image: boolean vector operations]

Comment: Please try to explain more what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Did the comment and picture help with clarity?

Comment: Yes that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the simple answer is no. You can execute menu commands as a workaround:

See this question on graphicdesign.stackexchange.com
- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81186/calling-pathfinder-divide-through-javascript-in-illustrator/82631

You could also use InDesigns pathfinder https://github.com/ExtendScript/wiki/wiki/Pathfinder